# Current property of custom view not updating correctly

Tags: c#, acumatica

I've created a view on the Stock Items page that displays all items with the same item class as the item being viewed. The view displays correctly, but the current property is not correct. For some reason, the `relatedItems.Current` record is always the item currently on the page, not the item being selected in the grid.

I have the callback function on the ASPX page and the `InventoryCD` LinkCommand calling this function. What's weird is I have this same code on the Item Classes screen, and it works perfectly.

The `Current` property of my custom view is always the record that was clicked on. I have the `SyncPosition` setting set to true for the grid. Could there be a problem because I'm referencing `InventoryItem` on an `InventoryItem`? Thanks

```
public class InventoryItemMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{

    #region Event Handlers

    public PXSelectReadonly<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.itemClassID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>, And<InventoryItem.inventoryID, NotEqual<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>> relatedItems;

    public PXAction<InventoryItem> ViewCurrentItem;

    [PXButton]
    protected virtual void viewCurrentItem()
    {

        InventoryItem row = relatedItems.Current;

        // Create the instance of the destination graph
        InventoryItemMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
        graph.Item.Current = row;

        if (graph.Item.Current != null)
        {
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "Item");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you have specified `DependOnGrid` property for your action in page:-

```html
<CallbackCommands>
    ...
    <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="ViewCurrentItem" Visible="true" DependOnGrid="RelatedGridID" />
</CallbackCommands>
```

Property is explained in T200 Training material

[image]

Alternate option would be to utilize AllowEdit of PXSelector - you will not need the Custom Action.

Example

```html
<px:PXGrid … >
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel …>
        <Columns>
        …
        </Columns>
        <RowTemplate>
            <px:PXSegmentMask runat="server" ID="CstPXSegmentMask2" DataField="InventoryCD" AllowEdit="True" />                                              
        </RowTemplate>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
</px:PXGrid>
```

To change the item in the same page,

Each data view should refer to a unique main data access class (DAC) unless you want to display the same data record in multiple container controls. With that, you need to create a new DAC to represent Related Item inherited from `InventoryItem` with definition of new abstract classes for the data fields of the derived class used in BQL statements.

```c
[Serializable]
public class RelatedInventoryItem : InventoryItem
{
    public new abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { };

    public new abstract class itemClassID : IBqlField { };
}
```

And your dataview should be

```c
public PXSelectReadonly<RelatedInventoryItem,  
                         Where<RelatedInventoryItem.itemClassID,   
                               Equal<Current<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>,
                          And<RelatedInventoryItem.inventoryID, 
                            NotEqual<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>> 
                        relatedItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

@DChhapgar Yes, I have the DependOnGrid set correctly. Here's all of the relevant code:

```html
<px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="ViewRelatedItems" Visible="true" DependOnGrid="relatedItemsGridID" /></CallbackCommands> 
....
    <px:PXTabItem Text="Related Items">
    <Template>
        <px:PXGrid runat="server" ID="relatedItemsGridID" SkinID="DetailsInTab" Width="100%" SyncPosition="True" DataSourceID="ds" >
            <Levels>
                <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="relatedItems">
                    <Columns>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryCD" Width="100" LinkCommand="ViewRelatedItems"/>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" Width="100" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ItemClassID" Width="100" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Descr" Width="200" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ItemStatus" Width="100" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ItemType" Width="100" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="KitItem" Width="60" /></Columns>
                    </px:PXGridLevel></Levels>
            <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
            <Mode AllowAddNew="False" AllowDelete="False" AllowUpdate="False" /></px:PXGrid></Template></px:PXTabItem>
....
```

Using the  `AllowEdit` of `PXSelector` works, but I would like to change the item in the same page, so ideally the user would click on the item, the Inventory ID/Inventory CD field in the header would be populated with the clicked Item, and the changes committed.